# Swagger produces too long constant for default response body

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-codegen

Basically, it's required to generate valid *Java8* models and controller class with *swagger-codegen-maven-plugin*.

I have swagger 2.0 spec, containing model definitions with array fields, where each array item in turn contains it's own array of models.

Swagger successfully generates java models and annotated interface,
this interface contains default response body, representing autogenerated json response example for root model and all it's submodels.
Actually, this is a problem:

For each array field swagger always produces 2 items, 2 more subitems for each items's array field and so on, which results in very long string constant in java.
Swagger generates this string without any problem but java compier simply just can't handle it and falls with compilation error: *constant string too long*.

I've tried to find a way to reduce elements count in model array or disable example body generation at all. Looks like there's no obviouse config to control this.

Is there any way to disable default body generation or any other stuff to control generated string length?

Autogenerated code cannot be commited, so there's no way to manually fix generated code and use it afterwards. It's required to get compilable java code after swagger-codegen plugin finishes.

There's codegen maven config, used for generating sources (tested for 2.3.1 and 2.4.0 versions):

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <configOptions>
                        <sourceFolder>java</sourceFolder>
                        <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                    </configOptions>
                    <generateSupportingFiles>false</generateSupportingFiles>
                    <addCompileSourceRoot>false</addCompileSourceRoot>
                    <generateApiDocumentation>false</generateApiDocumentation>
                    <generateApiTests>false</generateApiTests>
                    <generateModelDocumentation>false</generateModelDocumentation>
                    <generateModelTests>false</generateModelTests>
                    <ignoreFileOverride>${project.basedir}</ignoreFileOverride>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: see also  https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/2186 or https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/9055

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I've found the problem.

The trick was in adding **examples** section for the **response** which overrides default example generation in swagger.

There's still a problem in swagger generator itself - it can't produce valid java code for large response models and still limited with java constant string length.

Working response spec part looks like this:

```
    responses:
     200:
      description: Some text
      schema:
       $ref: '#/definitions/Model'
      examples:
       stub:
```

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, I didn't have stub, hence given an empty string as example the for the model

```
modelName:
  type: object
  example: '' 
  properties:
```